# Handing chrome popup through python selenium-chrome

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to handle chrome extension through selenium but i dont know how to handle the popup after clicking download(shown below)

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from os import system
import time
import subprocess

address = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir='
process = subprocess.Popen(address)
time.sleep(2)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
time.sleep(2)
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
time.sleep(2)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=options)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/martian-wallet-aptos-sui/efbglgofoippbgcjepnhiblaibcnclgk")
driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div").click()
```

popup shown right after this script cannot be handled with switch_to.window or driver.switch_to.alert functions.

Or is there another way for downloading chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot interact with those kind of popups through selenium because they are not part of the HTML. When the popup opens, you can accept it by pressing first the left arrow on the keyboard and then the enter key. In python you can do this with `pyautogui`:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('left')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot interact with anything that is not within the current context (active popup, active frame, etc).

In order to use extensions as part of your selenium tests, the recommended approach is to load the extension as part of your browser initialization logic. Something like the below (Code is from this page - https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-chrome-extensions-in-selenium)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension("path/to/your/extension_file.crx")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

If you specifically need to test the install step (or, the extension you need to install is dynamic), you'd need to do something like what's mentioned in the other answer, ie., add a different automation tool to your test setup and handle the native popup window with that.